# PrimeFaces Command Button actionListener does not fire

Tags: primefaces

I am using prime face for a web application, I'm having this problem which is I have a prime face Command Button with an action listener, when I click that button the actionListener doesn't get fired.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{cart.cartItems}" rendered="#{not empty cart.cartItems}">
<p:columnGroup type="footer">
            <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="3" footerText="Wallet Balance (#{cart.displayWalletAmount}) " style="text-align:right" />
                    <p:column>
                        <p:panel id="walPayPanel">
                            <p:inputText value="#{cart.payWalletAmount}" maxlength="7"  size="5" id="walAmount" />
                            <p:spacer width="10" />
                            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{cart.updateTotalAmount}" update="totPay,totPaybel" id="iconOnly" title="update" icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
                        </p:panel>

                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>  
                    <p:column colspan="3" footerText="Total Payble: "  style="text-align:right"  />  
                    <p:column><p:panel id="totPay"><h:outputText  id="totPaybel" value="#{cart.totalPayble}"/></p:panel> </p:column>                  
                </p:row>

            </p:columnGroup>                

        </p:dataTable>
```

And this the relevant code in the bean,

```
public void updateTotalAmount() {
    log.info("Entering updateTotalAmount()");
            log.info("Pay wallet Amount : "+payWalletAmount);
        // Double total = getCartTotal();
        if (payWalletAmount < 0.0) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "Wallet Amount cannot be a minus value", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

        } else if (payWalletAmount > (walletAmount)) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "Wallet amount cannot be exceeded the available balance", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

        }       

}
```

Interesting thing is if I placed above command button out side of the data table, action listen is getting fired. Even if I add Actionevent param in the bean method, it doesnt work. Can someone tell me how can I solve this problem? Can this be done without moving the command button outside from data table or columnGroup?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible things that could help you. One is adding '()' to your actionListener. Some people previously reported that this can fix the problem:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{cart.updateTotalAmount()}" update="totPay,totPaybel" id="iconOnly" title="update" icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
```

The other suspicious thing is your `update` statement. Try removing it and see if the button works. If it does, that means that you probably have to change it to: `update=":totPay,:totPaybel"`

Let me know if it helped, if not I will try to come up with other possible solutions.

**Edit 1:**

I have noticed similar problem recently that I managed to solve by changing the method signature to:

```
public void updateTotalAmount(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
```

and keeping the listener:

```
 <p:commandButton actionListener="#{cart.updateTotalAmount}" update="totPay,totPaybel" id="iconOnly" title="update" icon="ui-icon-refresh" />
```

Also make sure that your bean is still alive (`ViewScoped` for example).

Did you manage to fix your problem differently?

Comment: thanks but it didnt work, did both modification one by one, first one didnt work, second option throws an error. `javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier ":totPay" referenced from "confirmForm:j_idt57:iconOnly".`

Comment: Ok, try to remove update completely and add the (). If this is not it, can you post more of your page (trying to reduce it to the minimum size, but with the error still happening).

Comment: xhtml code `<h:form id="confirmForm"><p:dataTable var="c" value="#{cart.cartItems}"><p:column><h:outputText value="#{c.itemPrice}" /></p:column><p:columnGroup><p:row><p:column colspan="3"/><p:column><p:panel id="walPayPanel"><p:inputText value="#cart.payWalletAmount}" id="walAmount"/><p:commandButton actionListener="#{cart.updateTotalAmount()}" id="iconOnly" title="update"/></p:panel></p:column></p:row><p:row><p:column colspan="3"/><p:column><p:panel id="totPay"><h:outputText id="totPaybel" value="#{cart.totalPayble}"/></p:panel></p:column></p:row></p:columnGroup></p:dataTable></div></h:form>`

Comment: bean class `@ManagedBean(name="cart")
@SessionScoped
public class ShoppingCartServiceBean implements Serializable{
  
private List<RestCartItem> cartItems;
private String transactionFee, totalFee,displayWalletAmount; 
private Double cartTotal,totalPayble,walletAmount,payWalletAmount,tot,trnsFee = 0.0; 

public void updateTotalAmount() {
  log.info("Entering updateTotalAmount()");
  //some code here
 } 
}`

Comment: It seems like you are closing a div before you close a form- tag mismatch?

Comment: nope, if that is the case it will be a error at run time. and eclipse shows such errors. that piece of code is not the whole thing, that is the minimum which i can fit in to here and there are a lot more div tags and all of them are properly closed, as i said earlier, if i place that command button out side the data table it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your p:dataTable with a `<h:form></h:form>`.